# Can't execute a command: no such file or directory / Java

Tags: java, jar, process, terminal

I am trying to run a `.jar` file via another program. For example, I have a `HelloWorld.jar` file which opens a dialog saying "Hello World". And I have a `Test.jar` program. When I do something in the `Test.jar` (i.e. click some button), it should run the `HelloWorld.jar`.

The way I am currently doing so is running a terminal command `java -jar HelloWorld.jar` using `ProcessBuilder`. However, I get this error:

```
Debug: "C:\Users\Asus\.fairplay\data\apps\Amnesia\.tmp524\.bin" exists: true
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java -jar Amnesia.jar" (in directory "C:\Users\Asus\.fairplay\data\apps\Amnesia\.tmp524\.bin"): CreateProcess error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at me.darksidecode.fairplay.client.util.Utils.execute(Utils.java:74)
    at me.darksidecode.fairplay.client.app.AppLauncher.launch0(AppLauncher.java:61)
    at me.darksidecode.fairplay.client.app.AppLauncher.launch(AppLauncher.java:37)
    at me.darksidecode.fairplay.client.app.AppLoader.downloadAndRun(AppLoader.java:28)
    at me.darksidecode.fairplay.client.gui.frame.GuiLauncher.onPacketReceiving(GuiLauncher.java:165)
    at me.darksidecode.fairplay.client.core.FairPlayClient.lambda$processPacket$1(FairPlayClient.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 7 more
```

I am **100%** sure that both the file and the directory **exist**, and I even checked that. As you can see in the error over here, there is also a debug message proving that.

My code for command execution:

```
public static Process execute(final String path, final String cmd, final boolean removeJavaOptions) {
    File f = Files.getFile(path);
    System.out.println("Debug: \"" + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\" exists: " + f.exists());

    try {
        final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

        pb.directory(Files.getFile(path));
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        if (removeJavaOptions)
            pb.environment().remove("_JAVA_OPTIONS");
        return pb.start();
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The usage of this method itself:

```
Utils.execute(bin.getAbsolutePath().replace(bin.getName(), ""), "java -jar " + bin.getName(), false);
```

**I have not found any useful answers to this question on StackOverflow or anywhere else yet.** Hopefully there is a solution to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ProcessBuilder` constructor accepts either a `List<String>`, or a varargs (several strings), e.g.

```
new ProcessBuilder( "command", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3" );
```

Instead of passing it the commands and the arguments separately, you have tried to pass it the command together with the arguments in the same string.

The builder interprets the first argument as the name of the command. Thus, it believes that you are trying to run a file called `java -jar Amnesia.jar`. It thinks you simply have an executable file with spaces in its name. But of course, the operating system can't find such an executable file.

What you should do is run the command with the arguments separated from the command, that is:

```
new ProcessBuilder( "java", "-jar", "Amnesia.jar" );
```

So you'll need to reconstruct your `execute` method, such that either the `cmd` parameter is a `List<String>`, an array (`String[]`), or it is the last parameter and is a *varargs* parameter.